# How to know for the postback from tree view control in asp?

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Is there any way to know about the postbacks whether it is generated from expanding or collapsing tree view control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ASP.NET TreeView:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvMain" runat="server" ExpandDepth="10"     OnTreeNodeExpanded="tvMain_TreeNodeExpanded" OnTreeNodeCollapsed="tvMain_TreeNodeCollapsed">
    <RootNodeStyle Font-Bold="true" />
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Root" Value="Root">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Link2" Value="Link1"></asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Link2" Value="Link2"></asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>

    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Your code behind:

```
Protected Sub tvMain_TreeNodeCollapsed(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeEventArgs)
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        If e.Node.Value.Equals("Root") Then
            'Do your stuff'
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub tvMain_TreeNodeExpanded(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeEventArgs)
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        If e.Node.Value.Equals("Root") Then
            'Do your stuff'
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The trick is to handle the OnTreeNodeCollapsed Event and the OnTreeNodeExpanded Event. Next, you choose a Value for your rootnode - that is the first and single child node. You add nodes to your root node and make sure they have different Values than your root node.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    string ControlID = string.Empty;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]))
    {
        ControlID = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
    }
}
```

Source : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134614/Way-To-Know-Which-Control-Has-Raised-PostBack

One more link : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/82086/How-to-know-which-control-has-raised-a-postback